# Blocking a PR based on JIRA ticket status

Tags: github, jira, pull-request

This can sound a bit weird but here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- For certain JIRA tickets that will need to go under release management, I want to block the PRs associated with those tickets in Github. So for instance, let's say one ticket has a specific label, component, whatever in JIRA that tells this has to go under release management scrutiny, I want the PR to be blocked from being merged until we approve that change (the approval probably means a change on the JIRA ticket itself). I have to say we have many other tickets that don't require this formal approval and therefore we should allow PRs there to continue operating as they do now.

Also, all PRs merge into main, so I'd like to avoid having to create a new branch just for release management, but I understand this is a probably natural effortless option.

- Alternatively, if there's no way we can control this from JIRA, I'd like to block *some* PRs on main branch so they require a specific person to sign-off. And again, if I can do this with just one branch would be great...from what I've seen and read so far, this is not an option.